Is this notation consistent? $x \in \{x \mid P(x)\}$
In proofs that prove set equivalences, I have often seen that: First we write set in set builder notation is defined, e.g. $A = \{x \mid P(x)\}$. Then we kind of just forget that we have written $\{x \mid P(x)\}$ and just worry about what the predicate $P(x)$ says. But the variable that we then choose to follow is $x \in A$. But if we write that, we have written
\begin{equation}
x \in \{x \mid P(x)\}.
\end{equation}
Is that consistent, and would it be exactly equivalent to writing, say,
\begin{equation}
y \in \{x \mid P(x)\}.
\end{equation}
And what would be preferred? The fact that $x$ is repeated feels wrong to me. I can see that that the benefit of the former is that you need to introduce fewer symbols. But is it okay to write it?

$x$ is a bound variable in $\{x \mid P(x)\}$, so you can $\alpha$-rename it to whatever you want: $x \in \{ x \mid P(x) \}$ means the exact same thing as $x \in \{y \mid P(y) \}$ (but it does not mean the same thing as $y \in \{ x \mid P(x) \}$, since that is a statement about $y$ and not $x$).
On the other hand, the expression $\{x \mid P(x)\}$ is not well-defined in ZF set theory, because we don't have unrestricted comprehension (see Russell's paradox, naïve set theory, etc.). We can only talk about $\{x \in A \mid P(x)\}$ for some set $A$.
